# Checking for signals above strength threshold over SDR on VHF

Tags: rf, python, sdr, vhf

So I have a small NooElec Software Defined Radio and I've got it working well with my Raspberry Pi using [GQRX](http://gqrx.dk/download/gqrx-sdr-for-the-raspberry-pi) as a controller and to visualize the SDR output.

My goal though is to use a python script to listen for pulses (10ms long every 1s) from small VHF beacons on animals that we've tagged. These tags give out a ping around 151MHz and I've been able to find them fine in my GQRX output but I would like to use the [`pyrtlsdr`](https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr) tool and matplotlib's [`mlab`](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html) functions to pull this into python so I can trigger some other equipment once that signal pulse is detected above a certain strength. Basically I'm using signal strength as a proxy for distance to zero in on the tag. My experience with RF is pretty limited but I think this should be a relatively basic operation.

So I ingest the samples from the SDR with `pytrlsdr` use `mlab.magnitude_spectrum()` to convert that to signal strength and frequency in order to find out whether or not the signal meets my threshold and this sort of works but I feel like I'm pushing through the dark and wanted to double check my methods and see what else I need to check for when running through this procedure.

Specific Questions:

- I'm not exactly sure how the find the peak but have been toying
  around with [`scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html), is this appropriate for peak finding in this situation? If so how do I find the widths for the peaks? Empirically?
- What is the ideal sampling rate? How can I calculate this?
- Is anything about this method going to hurt my detection radius, as usual it is critical that is a large as possible. Any way to improve the detection radius?

So here is my current method:

```
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
from matplotlib import mlab

sdr = RtlSdr()

# configure device and settings
sdr.sample_rate = 2.048e6  # Hz
sdr.center_freq = 151e6     # Hz
sdr.gain = 'auto'
num_samples = 1024
threshold = -0.10 # empirically derived

my_samples = sdr.read_samples(num_samples)
magnitude_values, freqs = mlab.magnitude_spectrum(my_samples)

above_threshold = []
for index, magnitude in enumerate(magnitude_values):
    if magnitude > threshold:
        above_threshold.append([magnitude, freqs[index]])
```

I certainly have some reading up to do on RF Signal Analysis but I feel like I'm close to a working system.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers in the SIgnal Processing group https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

But since the results are complex numbers, wouldn't you just calculate magnitude using Pythagorean's theorem?

Comment: Okay thanks @VincePatron I'll look around there! In the meantime updated with some progress.